# User profile picture do not show in OOTB People webpart for Sharpoint on-premise 2019

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, people-picker

The out of the box People webpart does not show the User image, that has been uploaded in the User profile for SharePoint on-premise. My site configuration has also been done for the same. Still when the webpart is published, the image are not displayed in the webpart.

[image]
[image]

The picture has been uploaded for the user profile as shown below.
[image]

URL for saved Picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No issues here running the Oct 2020 PU.

You might try running the timer job User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization. This will push the picture from the UPSA to the Site Collections.

You can then empty the browser cache/perform a hard refresh (F5).